# Showing rows in table headers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like

```
id       course       activities   

1     Microbiology      Quiz1
2     Microbiology      Quiz2
3     Microbiology      Quiz3
4     Microbiology      Quiz4
```

I need to show in php file as table header

```
Quiz1   Quiz2   Quiz3    Quiz3  Quiz4
```

And this is my code

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM activity');
while($row = mysql_fetch($sql))
{
    $activities $row['activities'];
}
echo '<table>
       <tr>
        <th>'.$activities.'</th>
       </tr>
     </table>';
?>
```

Comment: Is there a question in this ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to reorganize your code :

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM activity');

echo '<table><tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<th>'.$row['activities'].'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

//your data rows here

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: If this code doesn't work, there's something wrong in amount. For example, are you sure your mysql query is right, isn't it `SELECT * FROM activity WHERE course = 'Microbiology'` ?

Comment: @ronquiq  It will show only one Quiz4 header in ur code as the displaying header code is out of the while loop whereas here its in

Comment: Ow ! Didn't notice... Use `mysql_fetch_array`, not `mysql_fetch`, which doesn't exists. (thanks @u_mulder)